# Does the following variant of Lipschitz continuity have a canonical name?

Tags: analysis, reference-request, continuity, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a function between metric spaces and $x_0 \in X$. Does the following property have a canonical name? Or is it equivalent to something which is more well-known?

> There is a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ and a constant $L > 0$ such that $d(f(x_0),f(x)) \leq L \cdot d(x_0,x)$ for all $x \in U$.

I would call this "locally Lipschitz at $x_0$" for the moment. We have the following properties:

- locally Lipschitz at $x_0$ $\implies$ continuous at $x_0$
- [Locally Lipschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) $\implies$ Lipschitz on a neighborhood of $x_0$ $\implies$ locally Lipschitz at $x_0$

The converse in the last implication does not seem to hold, since Lipschitz on a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ would mean that $d(f(x),f(x')) \leq L \cdot d(x,x')$ holds for all $x,x' \in U$ (not just for $x=x_0$).

Comment: Among other places, see the earlier parts of the recent paper [*Lipschitz extensions and approximations*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022247X20304042) by Valentin Gutev (2020; [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.07205.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks. There, the point $p$ is also not fixed. But the corresponding terminology would probably just be "Lipschitz in the point $p$"?

Comment: "Lipschitz at $p$" is fairly standard, I think --- parallel usage to continuous at $p,$ differentiable at $p,$ increasing at $p,$ etc. To me "in the point $p$" sounds really strange.

Comment: Ok. Yeah, "in $p$" was a bad translation from German (my native language).

Comment: Incidentally, "locally Lipschitz at $p$" is a stronger condition than "Lipschitz at $p$" (consider $f(x) = x$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is irrational for $p = 0$; $f'(0) = 1$ but $|f'(x)| = \infty$ for $x\neq 0),$ which goes against one's intuition that more words added produce a stronger (or at least, not weaker) property, so it's probably better to say "pointwise Lipschitz at $p$" for the 2nd property, especially if both are being discussed.

Comment: Regarding terminology like this, the situation is not all that standard (but the distinctions are well known), and this [2006 sci.math discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/9kU61P-TLOs/m/H7bsXeNAHrkJ) might be of interest. In addition to the 3 distinctions made there, I can think of another one that could be considered: For each open set $U$ containing $p$ there exists a nonempty open subset $V$ of $U$ $(p \notin V$ possible) such that the property in question holds throughout $V$ (in some global sense, or at each point in $V$; these possibly being different for some properties).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro In your  statement, which def' of "locally Lipschitz at $p$" do you use?

Comment: I would interpret "locally Lipschitz at $p$" to mean there exists an open set $U$ (equivalently, an open ball) and a number $K > 0$ such that for each pair of points in $U$ the difference quotient for $f$ relative to that pair of points is less than or equal to $K.$ The main reason for this version rather than the version in which we say $f$ is $K$-Lipschitz at each point of $U$ is so that these two notions can be considered separately. I think they're equivalent in locally compact metric spaces (such as ${\mathbb R}^n)$ but don't take my word for this without double-checking.

Comment: In my previous comment I forgot to require $p \in U.$

Comment: Alright. When you post an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been answered by Dave in the comments. The property is just called "Lipschitz at $x_0$".